# why OData is preferred over SCIM?

Tags: rest, odata, scim

I recently studied about Odata and SCIM protocol. Both are providing REST services but am not clear about the disadvantages of SCIM which makes OData better preference for Restful services.Could someone please help me understand the differences ?

Comment: IMHO, SCIM is more widely accepted by different data providers.

Comment: these are unrelated items which serve different purposes

Answer (score 5):

That's a great question and one I've had to deal with in the development of our private cloud identity platform.Here's my (long-winded) take:

OData (http://odata.org) is a set of standards for modeling and accessing data of all sorts: relational, hierarchical, graph, you name it. It provides a language for defining data models (read: schema) and a standard approach to defining the APIs to access that data. OData started out firmly rooted in XML, but has evolved to HTTP/JSON over the last couple of years.

SCIM (http://www.simplecloud.info/) started with a much more limited scope: to provide a REST API for provisioning identity data, i.e. users and groups. SCIM v2 expanded to include schema extensibility as well as search and CRUD operations. In this sense, SCIM’s evolution is very similar to that of Service Provisioning Markup Language (SPML). In a lot of ways SCIM is a RESTful, JSON-y version of SPML.

The two standards started with different goals, but have converged somewhat in terms of functionality. Even so, OData is substantially more expressive. A few areas come to mind:

- Query expressions – SCIM is limited to expressions comparing
  attributes to literal values, e.g. ~/Users?filter=surname eq “smith”,
  combined with “and”s and “or”s. OData supports comparison of
  attributes to other attributes, e.g. ?$filter=Surname eq Title, and
  even comparison of attributes of different entities. I suspect that
  SCIM’s limitation in this regard comes from the influence of LDAP on
  its designers and early use cases.
- Queries on complex data models – Both SCIM and OData support exposing
  relationships between resources using URLs. This allows you to create
  richer data models. But the SCIM query language doesn’t allow
  operations on navigation (“$ref”) attributes, so you can’t navigate
  between resources as part of a query. OData incorporates navigation
  properties as part of the data model, and as a consequence, you can
  use a single OData query to (for instance) “return all the people who
  work for my boss’s boss who are assigned to my project”. You can of
  course do this with SCIM, but it’s up to the client application to do
  the navigation, maintain state, and so on. OData is more like SQL in 
  that it lets you offload query complexity to the server. It’s a good 
  idea in general, and critical when the client is a constrained device
  like a phone.
- Functions and Actions – SCIM defines an API for CRUD and search
  operations, but that’s all. OData provides for the definition of
  other kinds of APIs. For instance, you can define an entity-bound API
  called “SendEmail” that accepts a message as one of its parameters,
  and the system would send an email to the entity in context. This is 
  a really powerful notion in my mind, and allows applications to
  discover APIs the same way it can discover everything else about an
  OData system. Functions can be used in query expressions too, so you 
  can ask things like “return all the customer whose
- Type system – SCIM doesn’t really provide a type system per se.
  Resources are classified by a resource type that defines the allowed 
  attributes for resources of that type, but that’s it. OData defines
  inheritance of types, abstract types, “open” (extensible) types and
  type conversion, and supplies a much wider range of primitive types
  (e.g. geolocation, streams, enumerations, etc. OData also allows you 
  to explicitly define referential constraints between entities.
- Extensibility – SCIM (in v2) supports the addition of new resource
  types and additional attributes to existing resource types. Because
  OData is data model driven, everything is extensible, including
  entities, properties, relationships, functions, and actions.

If OData is a so much richer approach to modeling data and defining APIs than SCIM, why bother with SCIM at all? Because SCIM was developed to solve a very specific problem (identity provisioning), it is quite a bit simpler to understand and simpler to implement than OData. If your application can provision identities to one system using SCIM 1.1., it can probably provision to lots of others. While provisioning identity information using OData is no more difficult than with SCIM, it's just more likely that each target OData platform will expose a somewhat different model, which means that you potentially have to tweak your code for each target. That's what SCIM was intended to address, and it succeeds at that. But if you want to expose a rich data model and a corresponding set of APIs (even if for identity information), OData far and away a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

SCIM is specifically for identity management (e.g., users and groups). OData is a general purpose framework for building RESTful web services. You could create a SCIM service using OData (with some minor differences in URI and payload formats).

Answer (score 0):

Like any pattern, to compare / judge you need to understand the problem their meant to address. They are an attempt to address **enterprise application integration**. Applications from different vendors on different OSs with different APIs need some common protocol to communicate. Think Finance App talking to HR app from different vendors.

So why REST? Because REST is built on HTTP which is a lowest common denominator standard (but not a bad one), meaning that everyone can play and port 80 is the only port open in every firewall.

OData is a more mature and comprehensive standard, but keep in mind its a standard not an implementation. With most vendors their implementation of the standard is incomplete or dated (Microsoft, Oracle, SAP). So before committing to anything ensure it has the features you need (real world).